# Delta table - instead of merge Im getting an overwrite

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

Im Running EMR ON Eks
Using Delta lake version 1.2.0.

My goal task is update daily changes into delta files (currently map to an external table on snowflake)

My key consist with 3 different columns (location, title, identifier)
I have my table `posts`
Im loading the table using pyspark with delta package and in my current context
I have the daily changes (including rows to update and rows to insert since they not fit to the key combination.
I use a very simple merge with updateAll and insertAl here is the curial code section

```py
table = DeltaTable.forPath(self.spark, table_data_location)

table
.alias('A')
.merge(updates_df.alias('B'),
  "A.location = B.location AND A.title = B.title AND A.identifier = B.identifier")
.whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
.whenMatchedUpdateAll()
.execute()
```

The table before the merge containing 19M rows.

After the merge it contain the exact same amount of the
`updates_df` dataframe.

if the `updates_df` had 1m rows then after the merge I'll have 1m rows table.

No idea what Im doing wrong

Comment: How do you check the data? Also, how many rows do you have in `posts` - check with `spark.read.table("posts").dropDuplicates(["location", "title", "identifier"]).count()`

Comment: @AlexOtt So, I revert to version 0, to get the initial 19m rows I had.
now I did the following: 

`from delta.tables import *
table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "s3://.../gold/posts/")
table.toDF().dropDuplicates(["location", "title", "identifier"]).count()
# Output number of rows 19,282,426`

Comment: Didn't mention, in my unit tests I test the function / class that does just that on fake mock dataframes and everything seems to be working as expected. no idea what the issue can be :/ no clue.

Comment: Could you print `table.toDF().count()`? Just to make sure there is no obvious error such as using a wrong location.